# How to return the value generated inside where clause in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, with-statement, neo4j-apoc, cypher-3.1

I have the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) 
WHERE ANY(x in keys(n) 
    WHERE round(apoc.text.levenshteinSimilarity(
       TRIM(
          REDUCE(mergedString = "", item in n[x] 
               | mergedString + item + " ")), "syn"), 4) 
                   > 0.8) 
RETURN n, r, k
```

How can I return the score generated inside the WHERE clause by the similarity function.

I am trying to do this with WITH, without luck:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) 
WITH *,  [x in keys(n) | [x, round(apoc.text. levenshteinSimilarity(TRIM(REDUCE(mergedString = '', item in n[x] | mergedString + item + ' ')), 'syn'), 4)]] as scores
WHERE [s in scores WHERE s[1] >= 0.8]
RETURN n,r,k,[s in scores WHERE s[1] >= 0.8] AS attr_scores
```

Comment: Can you please help? @jose_bacoy

Comment: Can you show us sample input, along with the expected output.

Comment: I am looking for a concept, Jose already helped me with the query but I need the scores also, I have updated the answer with latest solution, I am looking to make it efficient.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74479572/cant-apply-fuzzy-distance-function-in-a-cypher-query-that-checks-similarity-aga

Comment: @CharchitKapoor look at my edited answer and latest comment, I think it's already solved but it seems that I don't need to run ```[s in scores WHERE s[1] >= 0.8]``` twice, is there any way to filter all the results above 0.8 threshold and return only relevant attributes and their scores?

Comment: `[s in scores WHERE s[1] >= 0.8]` is present in two places, in the WHERE clause and in the return statement. Which one do you think is redundant? I think you can remove the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return only relevant attributes with a score > 0.8, update your list comprehension to this:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) 
WITH *,  [x in keys(n) | [x, round(apoc.text. levenshteinSimilarity(TRIM(REDUCE(mergedString = '', item in n[x] | mergedString + item + ' ')), 'syn'), 4)]] as scores
RETURN n,r,k,[s in scores WHERE s[1] >= 0.8 | s] AS attr_scores
```

Finally together with Charchit Kapoor we've found out the best solution:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(k)  
UNWIND keys(n) as key  
WITH n, r, k, key, round(apoc.text. levenshteinSimilarity(TRIM(REDUCE(mergedString = "", item in n[key] | mergedString + item + " ")), "syn"), 4) as score  
WITH n, r, k, collect({key:key, value:n[key], score:score}) as keyScores  
WITH n, r, k, [s in keyScores 
WHERE s.score >= 0.8 | s] AS attr_scores WHERE size(attr_scores) > 0 
RETURN *
```

Comment: How about the following solution but I would like to avoid redundancy and filter once the relevant attributes above some threshold:

```MATCH (n)-[r]->(k)
UNWIND keys(n) as key
WITH n, r, k, key, round(apoc.text. levenshteinSimilarity(TRIM(REDUCE(mergedString = "", item in n[key] | mergedString + item + " ")), "syn"), 4) as score
WITH n, r, k, collect({key:key, value:n[key], score:score}) as keyScores
WHERE ANY(s in keyScores WHERE s.score >= 0.8)
RETURN n, r, k, [s in keyScores WHERE s.score >= 0.8 | s] AS attr_scores```

Comment: Will be happy to hear your opinion on the above query @charchit-kapoor

Comment: It's good. This can be even better.
`MATCH (n)-[r]->(k) 
UNWIND keys(n) as key 
WITH n, r, k, key, round(apoc.text. levenshteinSimilarity(TRIM(REDUCE(mergedString = "", item in n[key] | mergedString + item + " ")), "syn"), 4) as score 
WITH n, r, k, collect({key:key, value:n[key], score:score}) as keyScores 
WITH n, r, k, [s in keyScores WHERE s.score >= 0.8 | s] AS attr_scores WHERE size(attr_scores) > 0
RETURN *` @SteveS

Comment: So the second with will filter out on a list of items on their attributes?
So every time I have a list of items like here (scores) and each item has fields, I need to run WITH?
@charchit-kapoor

Comment: First `WITH` calculates the scores, second `WITH`, collects them in a list. Third `WITH` filters out the list, to keep only elements with >= 0.8. And also it filters the records where no element with score >= 0.8 is present. In this way, we do the filtering of score only once, as compared to the above version, where we were first filtering in `ANY` function, and then in the next `WITH` clause. @steveS

Comment: Thanks a lot dear @Charchit-kapoor, great explanation. By the way can you share a good link to a "bible" of cypher?